# How to refresh kendo uploader widget using jquery

Tags: kendo-ui

kendo uploader works fine with upload, but kendo uploader holds certain data (kendo upload status) in html after form submit. How can I refresh kendo uploader using jquery?.

I needed something like below. Googled but with no hope.

```
$(".k-upload").data("kendoUpload").refresh();
```

Comment: It is not clear what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: is there any easy way to refresh the kendo uploader?

Comment: It is that *"refresh"* that its not clear. I have used kendo upload before and didnt need a *refresh*  on it, it dont event have a refresh method. What *data* you need to clear ?

Comment: Kindly see the link. http://prntscr.com/jb41u0 when I click on delete button, the file deletes/clears except the status of upload http://prntscr.com/jb40uu . I want to initialise/refresh or say clear the uploader datas. appreciating your response.

Comment: Did you tried [`clearFile()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/methods/clearfile) or [`clearAllFiles()`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/methods/clearallfiles) ?

Comment: thank you @DontVoteMeDown it did work!!! :) I was stuck with the issue, your help saved me

Answer (score 2):

showfilelist is default set to true. Set it to false.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/showfilelist